# Failed to get initial context or DataSource: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, weblogic12c, custom-authentication

I was trying to create Web-logic custom authentication provider. I created it and that was working well. Whereas when custom authentication is initializing, it will show this exception. But after that it is working perfectly. 
According to my opinion, weblogic is first trying to login as a weblogic user when server is starting. At that time this error is occurred. Next time, it won't show any error.

This is the error when it is trying to login as a weblogic user

```
userName    = weblogic
Data set name is = xxxDataSource
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee javax.naming.InitialContext@1ac745d4
Data set name is ######### = xxxDataSource
<Mar 6, 2018 6:27:47 AM CET> <Error> <Security.Authentication> <BEA-
000000> <Failed to get initial context or DataSource: 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve' xxxDataSource'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'xxxDataSource'
```

This is the user who is trying to login, when server start

[image]

your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the DataSource name is not found then that would mean it's not declared in your `server.xml` or `web.xml`. You should have something like this:

```
<Context>
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

</Context>
```

and/or

```
<web-app>
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

Check your authentication provider documentation on what to put in `server.xml` and/or `web.xml`.

Comment: It was declared in web.xml.  Data Source is taken second time. but It is not taken when server is starting.